# xampp: Apache WebServer is stopped

Tags: xampp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed xampp. When I open the xampp control panel (as root/another user) all the services start running when I click start except Apache WebServer. What can I do to make it start?

Comment: Find out why it didn't start by looking at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: xampp is not lampp.

Answer (score 9):

First, verify that the service is not already running:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

If it is running, to stop it, do

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Comment: it shows that:

"* apache2 is not running"
what can I do now?

Comment: You could start it with `sudo service apache2 start` but that will probably fail because of this other service that is already running. Find out what process this is by doing `sudo netstat -talp|grep http`. This will give you a process id. Kill that process, and try to start Apache2 again.

Comment: I have installed prestashop. for that maybe I need apache2 server.
Is there any other method so that can start apache in xampp without stopping apache2 server

Answer (score 6):

This is what works for me

1. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
2. Find `Listen 80` and change it to some other port (eg `Listen 8000`)
3. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`
4. Find `Listen 443` and change it to some other port (eg `Listen 4431`)
5. Open the file `/opt/lampp/lampp`
6. Search for the `testport 80` and replace it with `testport 8000`. Also change `testport 443` to `testport 4431`.
7. Now run `/opt/lampp/lampp start` (it works now).

Comment: But you are now using the wrong port numbers. Maybe it was a better approach  to find out what blocked port 80 and/or 443 instead.

Comment: Now you have to access the localhost with the port. I.e. before was omitted (80) now its `localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1):

At first you can try the two statements for apache
which are:

- sudo service apache2 status
- sudo service apache2 stop

Even after this if it doesnt work then your port (mostly 80) is busy with some process and to see the process on port 80: type this:-

- sudo netstat -lpn |grep :80

we have to kill the process in order for apache to work: type this

- sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:80`

and then by xampp apache should finally work, and it can be verified by viewing localhost and phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Start xampp by `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` this usually will return the error, already running etc.

Comment: it shows:

Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.5.19-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

and my Apache Webserver is not running and stopped.
What should I do to make other web server stop?

Comment: Try "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop" or "sudo service apache2 stop"

Comment: I've tried it. But Still it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

- Open your terminal and run the following command
  ***sudo apachectl stop***
- Try rerunning your apache server from xamp again.